# Php auto prepend file

Tags: php, apache

Is there a way i can include different file from different folder using single .htaccess file

Example:
`/`, should include init.php
`/admin`, should include admin_init.php

Currently i put .htaccess in every folder

.htacess in `/` folder contain:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file 'inc/init.php'
```

.htacess in `/admin` folder contain:

```
auto_prepend_file 'inc/admin_init.php'
```

When i use `Directory` directive, apache give me Internal Error

```
<Directory />
  php_value auto_prepend_file 'inc/init.php'
</Directory>

<Directory /admin>
  php_value auto_prepend_file 'inc/admin_init.php'
</Directory>
```

Is this can be done using single .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this can be done using single .htaccess file?

I don't think so, except if you have apache >= 2.4:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/admin/#">
    php_value auto_prepend_file 'inc/admin_init.php' # absolute path needed
</If>
<Else>
    php_value auto_prepend_file 'inc/init.php' # absolute path needed
</Else>
```

Other option is to do this in Apache configuration file if you can.

> When i use `Directory` directive, apache give me Internal Error

`<Directory>` can only be used in Apache configuration files, not in .htaccess.