# Structuring directory and get access to file from anoter file

Tags: php, file, path

I'm facing a trouble with this folders and files structure, any though please

```
root_folder
|
|__folder_one
|   |_  file_one.php
|
|__folder_two
|   |_  file_two.php
|
|__config.php
```

The code in file_two depends on some codes in file_one, note the folder_one is a folder with file_one used to carry some classes while the folder_two is a folder with file_two as controller

sample code in file_one

```
<?php
class Myclass{
//some code go here
}
?>
```

sample code in file_two

```
<?php
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/root_folder/folder_one/file_one.php');
//some code goes here
?>
```

Now: because I may have many files in folder_two and even sub folders i decided to create confi file which will avoid repetition of this line `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/root_folder`

sample code in config file

```
<?php

session_start();
//url to be used for file access
$url = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/root_folder';

?>
```

And the code in the file_two will look like this

```
<?php
include('config.php');
include_once($url.'/folder_one/file_one.php');
//some code goes here
?>
```

but the problem start from this line `include('config.php');` because it need to be re written like this

```
 <?php
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/root_folder/config.php');
    include_once($url.'/folder_one/file_one.php');
    //some code goes here
    ?>
```

I.m very sorry if you didn't undestand but i dont want each file to contain `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/root_folder` I want to replace it with `$url` for easy edit in single config file if there many files

Comment: If you have a system where web requests can _start_ at various folder depths, the only solution to get to that central config is to use various “path semantics” to get to it. Many systems have gotten around this by having, regardless of perceived depth, all requests routed through a single PHP file whose job is to further dispatch the request to subsequent folders. This makes folders in the URL effectively virtual from PHP’s perspective.

Comment: I guess you could also use the auto prepend feature to set `$url`, but I’m not a big fan of that personally. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22657956/231316